# RaspberryPi 4 use PWM via 3.5mm jack or GPIO PWM Pins?

Tags: audio

I am using the Adafruit TPA2016 to convert the audio PWM signal from the Pi4 to a better sounding analog signal.
The RaspberryPi4 has a few PWM Pins and the 3.5mm Jack which also uses PWM.

My question is will there be a difference in sound quality if I use the 3.5mm jack or the GPIO PWM Pins?
I mean both use PWM, so there shouldn't be a difference in sound quality right?

Comment: You would need an additional filter circuit if you use the GPIO pins https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-the-raspberry-pi-zero/audio-outputs

Answer (score 0):

All Pi models have 2 PWM channels (which can be used for audio), but regardless of the pins used the same PWM channels will be used.

It MAY be possible, with a better filter design, to improve performance but don't expect any significantly different result.

Comment: but does the 3.5mm jack share the same pwm with the pwm pins?